# How to edit FTP files with VIM and avoid typing the hostname everytime?

Tags: vim, ftp, sync

I need to edit remote files with vim, that are on a FTP server. THere's no SSH or SFTP access. Just FTP. I've tried syncing via curlftpfs, the files appeared in a local dir, but i cannot write to them, i get all sorts of errors, and when i manage to write files with random endings are generated on the server. index.php writes on server as index.phz, index.phy, etc...

I had sublime text 2 installed but cannot run it anymore after i installed new drivers for my graphic card. I've also tried n++ with WINE but no luck in openeing FTP files that are in a deeper directory level.

I've seen there are various approaches with vim to edit files on the FTP, but every single one needs typing like :e http://[user@]machine/path (with netrw plugin). I would really like to avoid anykind of repetition, rather set up a relative mapping. It's strange that there's not solution for vim since its a developer's tool mostly, sublime and npp already have that solved in a simple manner. typing on and on the same hostname/path etc. would break a simple DRY principle.

Idealy would be if i could cache the files locally with some syncing tool, and upload them to ftp mapping the path local -> remote, right after vim writes to a file, or i issue an upload command etc (without having to type file opened every time). There are plenty of files on the server so i cannot memorize them, It's important for me to have them cached locally so that i can access them fast and upload with a simple command.

I'm running Slackware 13.37 x64

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use netrw to display the content of a remote directory with:

```
:e ftp://user@domain.com/ <-- note the slash at the end.
```

from there you can open a file in another window with `P` or in the current window with `<CR>`.

Don't panic if you loose the file listing: it's still there and you can get it back with `:Rex`.

---

Or simply use a GUI FTP client like Filezilla or gFTP and its "Edit in…" feature.

Comment: I've tried the vim and filezilla method, and the filezilla is much faster than the vim, however if i open more files many new vim windows just makes too much mess. Will give gFTP a try. I just wish i could run sublime again since it beats any of the other ancient methods which make me counter productive :(

Comment: gFTP works like Filezilla: the windows mess is Vim's fault. In both FTP clients, you need to set this command as "editor": `"/usr/bin/gvim" --servername filezilla --remote-tab`.

Comment: Why can't you run Sublime? It works very well on Linux.

Comment: It did work, but I've updated some graphics drivers and it crashes on start now, don't wanna go into offtopic.

Comment: The --remote-tab works much better, wondering how can i set the command to add a buffer instead of a tab if i need to? –

Comment: See `:help clientserver` for all the options. You can use `--remote` instead of `--remote-tab`.

Comment: I'll mark this question as answered since you gave me the most helpful information and it answers my public question. However I'm still struggling to find a way to use the same functionality and a fluent workflow of the sublime text editor in a vim environment on linux. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Though you cannot simple use relative filenames (because the local working directory is different), you can use the filename-modifiers to refer to files relatively:

```
:edit %:h/another.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but another option is to use e.g. [curlftpfs](http://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem) (Slackware build [here](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/13.1/system/curlftpfs/)) to mount the FTP server to a mount point, then use your local text editor of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you pain, I love to use vim, and with the ftp client, it is almost like you have ssh. The workflow that I use is

1. Log into the ftp server using the open command `:e ftp://username@server/`
2. Create a new tab of the current selection `:tab split`
3. Move to the new tab `:tabn`
4. Navigate to the file in vim
5. When you are done editing the file, close the tab `:wq`
6. Repeat from step 2

I have found that this works the best.

The tabs in Vim are great, they can allow you to have a number of files and you can even yank `y` and delete `d` lines between open files in the same session. Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vim `ftp://hostname/path/` you'll get a directory listing.  If you work with this host often, you might want to bookmark it.  With netrw v153j, you can use `:NetrwMB filename(s)`; you can use mb to bookmark the current directory; and you can use `qb` to list the current bookmarks (and history).  Bookmarks and whatnot are available via the menu with gvim, too.  To go to a bookmark, use `gb`.

So, I'm suggesting that you bookmark the directory, return to the directory listing via `:Rex` or `gb`, and edit the files so listed.